# MySQL update table based on id in another table

Tags: mysql, database

This is what I tried

```
update site
set value_id = 4464551
where (select id from base
where name = 'myName' and
discriminator = 'abc' and 
system_id = 001)
```

**What I want** is

- update the value_id in trget site where id = (inner select statement)

**What I got**
- it updated all the rows in site

**Question**
- how can I get one id  that inner select statement returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should work.

```
UPDATE site
SET value_id = 4464551
WHERE site.id = (
    SELECT id 
    FROM base
    WHERE name  'myName' AND 
        discriminator = 'abc' AND 
        system_id = 001
)
```

Or, if you're expecting multiple rows to be updated:

```
UPDATE site
SET value_id = 4464551
WHERE site.id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM base
    WHERE name  'myName' AND 
        discriminator = 'abc' AND 
        system_id = 001
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get what you want without using inner sql statements, for example:

```
update site, base
set site.value_id = 4464551
where 
base.name = 'myName' and
base.discriminator = 'abc' and 
base.system_id = 001 and
site.id = base.id
```